# How can I get a HTML element to increase in size?

Tags: html, css

Please, it's **not** my HTML or CSS work :)

http://theironlady.airsoftware.co.uk/

I've been asked why the testimonials sometimes leak out of the parent container. I can only assume it is something to do with the script that cycles through the text? Can anyone shed any light on this?

```
<div id="testimoniesWrapper">
        <center>
        <div class="cycle-slideshow" id="testimonies" data-cycle-fx="fade" data-cycle-timeout="5000" data-cycle-slides="> div" style="position: relative;"><div style="display: block; position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 100; opacity: 1; visibility: hidden;" class="cycle-slide cycle-sentinel">
                    <blockquote style="visibility: hidden;">
                        Excellent service, ironing is done to a very high standard and very quickly - well worth the money.
                        <cite style="visibility: hidden;">Kelly McAneny
 from Tamworth
</cite>
                    </blockquote>
                </div>
                    <div style="display: block; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 80; opacity: 0; visibility: hidden;" class="cycle-slide">
                    <blockquote>
                        Excellent service, ironing is done to a very high standard and very quickly - well worth the money.
                        <cite>Kelly McAneny
 from Tamworth
</cite>
                    </blockquote>
                </div><div style="display: block; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 79; visibility: hidden; opacity: 0;" class="cycle-slide">
                    <blockquote>
                        Really pleased with the Ironing service from the Iron Lady - a life saver! Good value for money and even get a reminder when I've forgotten to deliver my items!
                        <cite>Liz Whitehouse
 from Tamworth
</cite>
                    </blockquote>
                </div>
        </center>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please include code in the question itself. The link will be meaninless to future users once the issues is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the child div's (.cycle-slide) are absolutely positioned.

Something which is absolutely positioned is removed from the "document flow" and as a result, the parent #testimoniesWrapper is not expanding to accommodate the children.

You can fix this with something like the following:

```
/* statically position slides so that their parent expands as expected.
   also hide them by default */
#testimoniesWrapper .cycle-slide {
    position: static !important;
    display: none !important;
}

/* show only the active child testimonial slide */
#testimoniesWrapper .cycle-slide-active {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Hope that helps. Good luck!

Comment: Exactly what I found too. Guessing it's propagating the divs in the jquery.cycle2.min.js